# Can I set a counter for the entries in a primefaces carousel element?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, counter

the title basically says it all. My goal is to display in the carousel Header something like "Element 1", "Element 2", etc.

Thanks for help

Heres how i kinda imagine it to look like:

```
    <p:carousel value="#{exampleBean.allElements}" headerText="Elements" var="el" itemStyleClass="elItem" counterVar="counter">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%" cellpadding="5" columnClasses="label,value">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Element #{counter}
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="SomeValue:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{el.sv}" />

            <h:outputText value="Some Other Value:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{el.sov}" />

        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Java collection API:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    Element #{exampleBean.allElements.indexOf(el) + 1}
</f:facet>
```